# Test class for REST Api

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, unit-test

```
@HttpPost
global static Map <String,String> doPost(String firstName, String lastName, 
    String phone, String email) {
    Lead lead = new Lead();

    Map <String,String> sta = new Map <String,String>();
    lead.FirstName = firstName;
    lead.LastName = lastName;
    lead.phone = phone;
    lead.Email = email;
    lead.Company = 'agf';
    lead.Status = 'Open - Not Contacted';

    Database.SaveResult db = Database.insert(lead, false);
    if(db.isSuccess())
    {
        sta.put('isSuccess','True');
        sta.put('leadId',lead.Id);
        sta.put('status','Success');
    }
    else
    {

        sta.put('isSuccess','False');
        sta.put('leadId','');
        sta.put('status','failure');
        sta.put('message','Requested Resources Does not found');
        sta.put('errorCode','Not Found');
        db.getErrors();

    }

    return sta;
}
```

how to write test code for above rest api service

Comment: can you add your class name ?

Comment: I have answered and hope that helps

Comment: Please Mark the answer as ticked so that helps others .Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//As Per Best Practice it is important to instantiate the Rest Context

 RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
  RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/Lead';  //Request URL
req.httpMethod = 'POST';//HTTP Request Type
RestContext.request = req;
RestContext.response= res;

MyRestResource s=new MyRestResource ();
 Map <String,String> stas=s.dopost('Test,'Test','1232','dummymail@test.com');

system.assert(stas.get('isSuccess')==true);//Similarly assert rest as well
```

For the REST API Wrapper classes i had blogged this as below to help

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2012/12/writing-test-classes-for-apex-rest.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Its not clear to me why the need to instantiate the RestContext in this case, because the method doPost does not even refer to the RestContext or the request?

Comment: @BradThomas - In practice for this OP's specific use case, it is not needed.

Comment: @mohith I followed your blog post on this issue and my question, what if I am not using any wrapper? Do I need to use a wrapper class?